# Group by mysql data that i need to expand one cell

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm working on a job at the minute where all the products within the store need to be brought in and show how many orders have been put through in-between that time period which was easy to do, but it also in the same table needs to split the quantity of the orders of that product into the separate months that it was ordered in, is there any way to expand the data from one cell that's been group and do a count on it and then separate it into sub months?

```
        $this->obDb->query ="SELECT vSku,fOrdertime,iOrderStatus,fPrice,SUM(iQty) as iQty,tShortDescription,fBuyprice as totalBuyPrice, vTitle FROM ".ORDERS.",".ORDERPRODUCTS."  WHERE iOrderid_FK=iOrderid_PK AND ";
        $this->obDb->query.=$statusquery;
        if(isset($this->request['start_date']) & $this->request['start_date']>0){
            $this->obDb->query.=" AND tmOrderDate >='".$this->request['start_date']."'";
        }else{
            $this->err=1;
            $this->errMsg=INVALID_START_DATE."<br>";
        }
        if(isset($this->request['end_date']) & $this->request['end_date']>0){
            $this->obDb->query.=" AND tmOrderDate <='".$this->request['end_date']."' GROUP BY vTitle";
        }else{
            $this->err=1;
            $this->errMsg.=INVALID_END_DATE;
        }

        if($this->err==0){
            $queryRs = $this->obDb->fetchQuery();
            $recordCount=$this->obDb->record_count;
            if($recordCount>0){
                $this->ObTpl->set_var("TPL_VAR_FROMDATE", $this->libFunc->dateFormat2($this->request['start_date']));
                $this->ObTpl->set_var("TPL_VAR_TODATE", $this->libFunc->dateFormat2($this->request['end_date']));
                for($i=0;$i<$recordCount;$i++)
                {
                    $this->ObTpl->set_var("TPL_VAR_STATUS","Incomplete");
                    if($queryRs[$i]->iOrderStatus==1){
                        $this->ObTpl->set_var("TPL_VAR_STATUS","Complete");
                    }
```

Comment: please add a sample of the layout that you'd like to see and the structure of the db tables you're querying.  Otherwise, the answer to your question is 'yes'.

Comment: Show some compact version if your current query and how you tried to change it. That will help understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've added the code that's being used. And if you select between two months say october and november it'll separate the orders to show like 3 in october and 2 in november.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking you could try

```
SELECT datecol, COUNT(id)
FROM your_table
WHERE datecol BETWEEN date1 AND date2
GROUP BY productId, YEAR(datecol), MONTH(datecol)
ORDER BY datecol
```